# How to allow the empty string when validating an integer value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Would like to check the validation for an integer value using JavaScript. At the moment, this works fine for integers, but I want it to allow an empty string, `""`

```
 function validateInt(inputString, columnName) {
    var errorOutput = "";

    var isNum = /^\d+$/.test(inputString);

    if (!isNum) {
        errorOutput += "<br>* Column " + columnName + " can only contain numbers. ";
    }

    return errorOutput;
}
```

An extra condition in the `var isNum = ...`? Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936293/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-whether-input-has-any-non-digits-in-it

Comment: inputString.length == 0 ?

Comment: @tymeJV, your suggestion is perfect. just small spell mistake. it is `isNaN(inputString)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `*` modifier  (zero or more) instead of the `+` modifier (one or more):

```
var isNum = /^\d*$/.test(inputString);
```

This will allow digit-only strings that have zero digits (i.e., the empty string) or some positive number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe going simply by using

```
if (!isNum || inputString === "") {
    ...
```

Comment: Should that be `!==` as the OP wants to allow `""`.  Also, the first check `!isNum` would be true when the value is empty.  So you need to check for empty value before using regex check. eg, `if (inputString !== "" && !isNum) {`

Answer (score 0):

Use modulus by 1, to allow empty string when validating integers:

```
var isNum = inputString % 1 === 0;
```

As said in the comments, this will allow hexadecimal, binary, and other number representations that can be parsed by [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).  It may not suit your particular case, if you don't want to allow those formats, but those are *technically* integers as well, for anyone who finds this and needs that functionality.  If you use `parseInt()` on the input before doing anything with it, I don't see any harm in using it (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: This still allow `""` as input.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown He said he wants to allow empty string

Comment: Be warned that this will allow hexadecimal and scientific notation in input strings: `"0xFAD" % 1 === 0` and `"1e10" % 1 === 0` are both `true`. See ES5's [*ToNumber Applied to the String Type*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1) for how strings are coerced to integers.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you cannot relive if(value) or if(value == "") in a single condition. You must write two statement for this. try if(value || value == '') also.